# Showing CreateView form on ListView url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have ListView class pointing to an url. I'd like to have a CreateView form on the same url, on top of each item of the list. So far no form is showing (only the button shows). How can I do this?

Right now I have these classes, both pointing at the same url on urls.py:

view.py:

```
class TheList(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name='item/post_create.html'

class CreatePost(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = [ 'post' ]
    template_name_suffix='_create'
```

Update. Now the textarea is showing, but submitting the form does not save the data:

```
class CreatePost(CreateView):
    class PostForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ['post'] 
            widgets = {
            'post': forms.Textarea()
        }

class TheList(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name='item/items.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TheList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CreatePost.PostForm
        return context
```

Comment: the form used in `CreateView`, you can send it via `get_context_data()` to the template, so you will have access to the form in your list view template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get_context_data()` method of your `ListView` to add the form to the context of your template:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = <your form>
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the textarea is showing, but submitting the form does nothing (no data saved). The HTML is the same one I used in another app that worked (with separate url). What might be the problem?

Comment: @thebot are you posting the form to your `CreatePost` view?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question.

Comment: checked answer for your previous answer, since the textarea did show.

Comment: @thebot rhank you. You can ask a new question describing your new problem to incease the chance of receiving a reply